# iOS9 where to find a comprehensive list of tweaks required to modernize iOS8 projects?

Tags: error-handling, ios8, ios9, xcode-project

I have a number of projects built for iOS7 and 8. Now I'm deploying these on iOS9 using xCode7 and see that things are breaking.

First the HTTPS requirement of TLS1.2, which requires a plist change. Then the keychain sharing bugs where OSStautus error -34018 is popping up, requiring keychain sharing plist capability to fix. Then there's static libraries that are not compiled using bitcode. I'm sure there are many more.

**Is there a comprehensive list of common errors that occur from iOS8 to iOS9 migration and how to fix them?**

Comment: I'm VERY curious about this too, and many others must be.  Why no responses?